# How can I count how many inidividual values of "Localidad" without repetition my dataframe has where the value of "Delegación" has a specific value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe called "MPSG" which has a column called "Delegación" and a column called "Localidad". Those values are related, each Delegación have a certain amount of Localidades. **I want to know how many unique Localidades I have when the value of Delegación is for example "26SONORA"**. I know that I have to use *length(unique(MPSG$Localidad))* to know how many unique values I have but I dont know how to do it when the Delegación in "26SONORA". I hope I was clear and you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `dplyr` s `filter`, `summarise` and `n_distinct` . Try:

```
library(dplyr)

MPSG%>%
filter(Delegación == "26SONORA")%>%
summarise(localidades_unicas=n_distinct(Localidades))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
df_new <- MPSG[MPSG$Delegación == "26SONORA", ]

length(unique(df_new$Localidad))
```

I hope, I can help